# How can I run Mongo client on a PC which is on same network as PC running Mongo server

Tags: mongodb, networking, server, database-connection, local

I have two windows 10 PCs on my home network.

On both PCs I have installed the latest MongoDB community edition (as of mid Jun 2020).

On each PC, I can open win console and run 'mongo' and I get the prompt.

However, I want to run 'mongo' on one PC but connect to the databases on the other PC.
Let us say the other PC has IP address 192.168.0.42.

If I try the following, and many other variants, I just can't get to the prompt where I can issue commands.

```
mongo --host "mongodb:192.168.0.42:27017"
```

What am I missing?
Please note all I have done is install MongoDB on both PC's and nothing more.

Do I need to add users to be able to attach?

If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Try `mongo mongodb://192.168.0.42:27017/`

Comment: That does not work either.
Since the post, I have updated the local mongod config file to bind to address 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 and confirmed that I can locally connect if I specify 192.168.0.42 which did not work until I changed the config file.

Strangely, trying mongo mongodb://192.168.0.42:27017/  results in no addition to the mongod log file in the server, *but* if I use my browser and set the address to   //192.168.0.42:27017 then it fails as expected but I DO see an entry in the log file that a connection was established.

Comment: Hence connection from browser in the 2nd PC to 192.168.0.42 results in a log entry.
I even tried making a 'raw' connection using Putty to that same addr/port and no entry in log file.

Comment: Use `mongo` shell and provide full output here.

Answer (score 2):

By default, MongoDB only accepts client connections from the localhost.

In order to connect to a remote MongoDB server, perform the below actions on the remote Windows 10 PC.

1. Open the `mongod.cfg` file on your editor of choice with `Admin` rights (Open notepad as Administrator and open this mongod.cfg file in that notepad). Usually, this file is located in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\<MongoDB Version>\bin` unless you changed it.
2. Find the below lines in the opened config file.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Change these lines to the following and save the file

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

3. Restart the MongoDB server PC after the above-mentioned changes are made.

**Note:** You can avoid restarting entering the below commands in Command Prompt with admin rights. But I recommend that you restart your PC.

```
net stop MongoDB
net start MongoDB
```

4. Enter one of the below commands on the client PC to connect to the remote MongoDB server.

**URI String Method:**

```
mongo "mongodb://192.168.0.42:27017"
```

**Standard CLI Method:**

```
mongo --host 192.168.0.42 --port 27017
```